# Need Mysql command to delete links in a table field

Tags: mysql

Have in my content in 600 sites links + linkword that I want delete per Mysql command. I want delete the whole "a href"  tag include the linked content. But not from 2 special user IDs

all datas in a mysql table called xx_content, the columns called xx_fulltext (theres the links), and xx_userid

I try this with the command
UPDATE xx_content SET xx_fulltext = REPLACE(xx_fulltext, 'a href', '');

but thats didn run

Comment: Please! 1. add your table definition to the question. 2. use proper formatting so that code gets readable. 3. explain what _exactly_ you mean by "didn't run" and 4. give a _specific_ example what string should be altered to what.

Comment: 1. ?
2. ok
3. Want to include the mysql command in my phpmyadmin dashboard, but I think thats not right

Comment: Hm. I still cannot see your table definition, so how your database table looks like. I still cannot see code formatting in your question. 3. ok, thanks and 4. ? The question does not look as if you changed it a bit, actually.

Comment: Ok now I understand.

It´s a joomla content table looks like:

`tablename_content` (`id`, `asset_id`, `title`, `alias`, `introtext`, `fulltext`, `state`, `catid`, `created`, `created_by`, `created_by_alias`, `modified`, `modified_by`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `publish_up`, `publish_down`, `images`, `urls`, `attribs`, `version`, `ordering`, `metakey`, `metadesc`, `access`, `hits`, `metadata`, `featured`, `language`, `xreference`)

The Links are located in the fields "introtext" and "fulltext". In the field "created_by" are the UserID